# Combining two Regular Expressions with AND&

Tags: regex, google-forms

Good evening,

I'm trying to regulate input on a Google Form. Since Google Forms allows me to input Regular Expressions for data validations, I've grudgingly began writing some.

### What I want:

- I want my input `String` to be lower or equal to `140` characters in length. Easy enough, with the RegExp: `^.{1,140}$`
- I want the input `String` to not contain the words `cat`,`dog` and `cardiologist`. So I've written a RegExp for it, using Negative lookahead: `^(?=^(?:(?!cat|dog|cardiologist).)*$).*$`
- But what if I want my `String` to ***BOTH*** be lower than 140 characters, and not contain `cat`, `dog` and `cardiologist`?
  **How do I combine these two Regular Expressions using the equivalent of AND between the two?**

Any help would be extremely appreciated. I've been trying for hours, but Regular Expressions hurt my brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
^(?:(?!cat|dog|cardiologist).){1,140}$
```

Just replace the wildcard after your tempered dot with `{1,140}` to quantify the length.  Follow the link below for a demo to a similar pattern.

## Demo

Comment: Simpler than I suspected, I was going to look for a combination of a positive lookahead for 1-140 chars and negative lookahead for the bad strings.

Comment: @Barmar [A good read](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) about the "tempered" dot.

Comment: Works great, friend-o! Thanks a lot, it was much simpler than I adicipated.

I'll be sure to read up on tempered dots.